# Reverse Geocoding With Google Map API And PHP To Get Nearest Location Using Lat,Long coordinates

Tags: php, google-maps, google-code, reverse-geocoding

I need a function to get an nearest address or city from coordinates(lat,long) using google map api reverse geocoding and php... Please give some sample code

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use the [getLocations](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GClientGeocoder.getLocations) method on the [GClientGeocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GClientGeocoder) object in the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html)

```
var point = new GLatLng (43,-75);
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
geocoder.getLocations (point, function(result) {
    // access the address from the placemarks object
    alert (result.address);
    });
```

**EDIT**: Ok.  You are doing this stuff server side.  This means you need to use the [HTTP Geocoding service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#ReverseGeocoding).  To do this you will need to make an HTTP request using the URL format described in the linked article. You can parse the HTTP response and pull out the address:

```
// set your API key here
$api_key = "";
// format this string with the appropriate latitude longitude
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=40.714224,-73.961452&output=json&sensor=true_or_false&key=' . $api_key;
// make the HTTP request
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
// parse the json response
$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
// if we get a placemark array and the status was good, get the addres
if(is_array($jsondata )&& $jsondata ['Status']['code']==200)
{
      $addr = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['address'];
}
```

**N.B.** The [Google Maps terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/policies#map) explicitly states that geocoding data without putting the results on a Google Map is prohibited.

> You can display Geocoding API results on a Google Map, or without a
> map. If you want to display Geocoding API results on a map, then these
> results must be displayed on a Google Map. It is prohibited to use
> Geocoding API data on a map that is not a Google map.

Comment: Thanks. I need the code in PHP because im going to show the address of latitude and longtitude in reports as records... please just me..

Comment: boss, part of being a programmer is the ability to abstract source code to your language. The Google Location Api is essentially the same in all used languages (including the GLatLng Syntax)

Comment: @Cannonade: I don't want to answer just to include the php sample code. Just a hint: there are a lot of php wrapper classes for the javascript api out there.

Comment: Thanks Henrik.  The ones I have seen just seem to wrap up the HTTP request.  I'll post a sample as soon as I get a chance to try one out. Feel free to post if you have the time :).

Comment: This code is very useful for me. I am new in php , so I would like to ask how to convert address language to another one ?

Comment: Look at here once : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding  API has been changed

Comment: TY just an upgrade... 
$lat = $_SESSION['lat'];
$lng = $_SESSION['lng'];
$googleURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$lng.'&key='. $api_key;