# MKReverseGeocoder returns cities that are not a city?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager, mkreversegeocoder

Hi i am using mkreversegeocoder to find the users current city.It works but when i try it in another location it gives the names of borough/district in my country (Turkey).For example it gives "istanbul" correct but there is no city name like "susurluk" in my country it is a district.Any idea why it returns me districts instead of city name? if you want i would post my code's

edit 1:

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


manager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
manager.delegate=self;
manager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[manager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)aManager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {


    MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder=[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    geocoder.delegate=self;
    [geocoder start];

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {

NSDictionary * addressDict= [placemark addressDictionary];

//NSString *country = [addressDict objectForKey:@"Country"];

NSString *city = [addressDict objectForKey:@"City"];

//change the country name into en_US

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];

NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];

NSString *country1 = [usLocale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:country1 forKey:@"country"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:city forKey:@"city"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}


 -(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

if (error.code == kCLErrorHeadingFailure) {
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Problem"
                                                    message:@"Can't find the location!"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
       }

 }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager1 didFailWithError:(NSError *)error        {

if (error.code != kCLErrorDenied) {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Problem"
                                                        message:@"Can't find the location!"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

  }

}
```

Comment: when i am at "balıkesir" the city and its district "susurluk" i use the app to see and it returns me susurluk instead of returning me "balıkesir".And a couple of more districts in "balıkesir".

Comment: what your doing by passing Coordinates(lat/long ) while initializing or something else;

Comment: you can check my codes i didnt understand what u mean sorry :(

Comment: now i am getting "Istanbul Province" returns right place.

Comment: I hope  MKReverseGeocoder takes SomeTime 23 Sec To Find Place Mark Before That If UpDate Location Its Not initlizing Properly Or you try To stop Updating Location When find Location In Update Did Location Manager

Comment: well this is my all code if there isn't any error return to me i never stop updating location.now i made it to update every 30 sec.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3168/discussion-between-srinivas-and-john-doe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the correct answer by using the google map api in which you have to send the lat/long of the place and you will get answer in the form of json/xml. Please check out this question

[Reverse Geocoding With Google Map API And PHP To Get Nearest Location Using Lat,Long coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054635/reverse-geocoding-with-google-map-api-and-php-to-get-nearest-location-using-lat-l)

Comment: thanks for the answer but do i need to connect it with php ? is iphone gps doesn't work alone? to find the location

Comment: IT work alone, but the answer you need that will be given by the google API.I have used it in many apps and all they are working fine.