# How to convert gps coordinates to address?

Tags: php, android, gps, street-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse Geocoding With Google Map API And PHP To Get Nearest Location Using Lat,Long coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054635/reverse-geocoding-with-google-map-api-and-php-to-get-nearest-location-using-lat)

How to convert gps coordinates ( latitude&longitude ) to address on Android or Php ?

My program should get address from given coordinates. For example :

Coordinates : 41.011576, 28.984852 --> Address : Cankurtaran Mh., Kennedy Cd, Istanbul, Türkiye

I hope, you can help me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class can do what you want for Android. You would use `getFromLocation` You would do it as so:

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    Address adress;
    String result = null;
    List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    address = list.get(0);
    result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
    //Now do what you want with result - this is the address.
```

You may want to make modifications, such as the 1 in `getFromLocation` if you want more than one location, or with the `address.getAddressLine` you may want to get more than one line.

You will want to put it within a `try {}` block and do it in a worker thread.

Answer (score 3):

Google reverse geocoding is your friend: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/