# Find closest airport (Lat,Lng) using provided Latitude Longitude in PHP

Tags: google-maps

I am working to get the latitude and longitude of nearest POI like airports, schools around a secondary latitude and longitude. So far i have searched and found the following API

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=airport,Nashik&sensor=false
```

Unfortunately it works with the address instead of the secondary latitude and longitude. and if I insert the latitude and longitude it gives me the address of that point. 
Is there a way to find the **nearest airport(latitude,longitude)** from the **provided (latitude,longitude)**. I am trying this in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Geocoding With Google Map API And PHP To Get Nearest Location Using Lat,Long coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054635/reverse-geocoding-with-google-map-api-and-php-to-get-nearest-location-using-lat)

Comment: @elsololobo i want the POI coordinates based on some provided coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

It's not that it fully meets your requirements and it has its limitations ("the maximum allowed radius is 50,000 meters", "radius must not be included" if you specify rankby = distance), but you can give it a try anyway.

Your requests could look like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.712784,-74.005941&rankby=distance&type=airport&key=<Your API Key>

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.712784,-74.005941&radius=50000&type=airport&key=<Your API Key>
```

Comment: This returns everything that is tagged as `airport`. I ran a few sample requests and their tagging is grossly wrong. Anything that is close to the airport or in the airport is tagged as airport and hence gets returned as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Aeris Weather** api. Here's the documentation https://www.aerisweather.com/support/docs/api/reference/endpoints/places-airports/

You'd want to use `closest` action with `largeairport` filter to avoid smaller/non commercial/military airports

ex: [https://api.aerisapi.com/places/airports/closest/p={lat,lng}&limit=5&radius=50miles&filter=largeairport&client_id={ID}&client_secret={SECRET}](https://api.aerisapi.com/places/airports/closest/p=%3Clat,lng%3E&limit=5&radius=50miles&filter=largeairport&client_id=%3CID%3E&client_secret=%3CSECRET%3E)

You can query using other place params too https://www.aerisweather.com/support/docs/api/reference/places/

A PHP package for the api https://packagist.org/packages/mariohbrino/aeris

They have 6 months free trial and then its $23/month for basic plan.